# What are database schema decompositions and why do we need them?

Tags: database, normalization, decomposition

- What is database schema decomposition?
- Why do we need decompositions?

Comment: When you did a Google search on 'database schema decomposition', did none of the top three entries help you?  The ones I saw all looked relevant, especially the [third](http://crpit.com/confpapers/CRPITV62Koehler.pdf): _A common approach in designing relational databases is to start with a universal relation schema, which is then decomposed into multiple subschemas._  This is using the term 'decomposition' to describe the process of 'normalization', for which you'd find an enormous number of hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is meant by this is that you start with one general schema for your database and decompose this into more specific schemas.

A good choice of more specific schemas can be determined using FK constraints defined on the schema, like join dependencies etc.

Why do you need it? I believe it significantly helps with normalization and manageability.